Clicking "showMore" from "useInfiniteHits" on my nextjs app removes Query from the URL
I am using Algolia in my nextjs app
import { useInfiniteHits, UseInfiniteHitsProps } from 'react-instantsearch-hooks-web'

 const { hits, isLastPage, showMore } = useInfiniteHits()

ISSUE: When I use showMore on button, it removes the query from my URL
Example:
1. Before clicking "show more"
http://localhost:3000/search?query=polo%20shirts
2.
After clicking "show more"
- Results are shown correctly
But URL gets reset without query and ONLY page is visible
http://localhost:3000/search?page=2  and so on
At this point, refreshing the page removes the filtered hits since now the query is gone and it only returns generic unfiltered hits.
-------
I tried creating my custom handler to retain the query but seems like there is a race condition and no matter how much I alter the router, query gets removed when using "show more"
  const handleShowMore = () => {
    // Load more results
    showMore()

    // Get the current page and update it, ensure the query is preserved
    const currentQuery = Array.isArray(router.query.query) ? router.query.query[0] : router.query.query || ''

    // Ensure the query includes the current query and page number
    const updatedQuery = { ...router.query, query: currentQuery }

    // Push the updated URL with the preserved query and new page number
    router.push(
      {
        pathname: router.pathname, // Retain the current pathname
        query: updatedQuery, // Update the query with new page and preserved query
      },
      undefined,
      { shallow: true }, // Shallow routing to avoid full page reload
    )
  }

